# Is phpseclib 1.0 compatible with PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, compatibility, phpseclib, php-7.3

This is a very simple question.

Is phpseclib 1.0.18 compatible with PHP 7.3?

I see no answer to this on their website, nor can I find any specific reference to PHP7.3 in this support site.

Comment: People appear to be using it with PHP 7.3, the latest commit was in the last 5 days and the composer.json file suggests anything over 5.6 is good.  https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1426  If you are asking if 1.0 can be used instead of 2.0, you probably need 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [1.0 changelog](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0/CHANGELOG.md), the 1.0.17 release included fixes for PHP 7.4:

## 1.0.17 - 2019-09-15

- fix PHP 7.4 deprecations

Additionally, the [Travis CI log](https://travis-ci.org/phpseclib/phpseclib/builds/585888874) shows a successful build against the 1.0 branch and PHP 7.3

[image: Screenshot of most recent Travis CI build showing success build for 1.0.18 branch]

So I would say yes, PHP 7.3 and the 1.0.18 branch are compatible.